# How can I add the currently logged in User as a field in Firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am submitting a form to Google Firestore Daatabase and I would like to add a field where the currently logged in user is added to the array that I am pushing.

I have tried using `firebase.auth().curentUser` but I cannot seem to get it to work. Sometimes it says undefined or just crashes my app. I need to get the firebase current user stored in a variable and then push that variable to Firestore.

Basically my problem is I can't figure out how to use variables when I am trying to write to the database for the current user. Thanks for any and all help, I need all I can get.

currentUser
firebase.auth().currentUser
some other `user.uid` code I saw etc.

```js
<script>
import db from "@/components/fbInit";
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
    name: "Popup",
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            name: "",
            employee_id: "",
            company: "",
            state: "",
            status: "",
            userId: ""
        };
    },
    computed: {
        userId() {
            return firebase.auth().currentUser
        }
    },
    methods: {

        submit() {

            const users = {
                employee_id: this.employee_id,
                company: this.company,
                state: this.state,
                status: this.status,
                name: this.name,
                userId: this.userId

            };
            db.collection("users")
                .add(users)
                .then(() => {
                    alert("Succesfully added to database");
                });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user's uid you have to use your `firebase.auth().currentUser` like this:

`userId() { return firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`

And then you can pass it to your `user` const.

```
const users = {
    employee_id: this.employee_id,
    company: this.company,
    state: this.state,
    status: this.status,
    name: this.name,
    userId: this.userId

  };
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something small on my part.

Comment: Glad it helped :)